# Need help understanding when I would need SSL certificates

Tags: facebook, ssl, notifications, push

I'm making an app which uses push notifications, and I know that I need a SSL certificate from the dev portal for that - which is fine.

Where I'm stuck is working out if I need more than one SSL certificate for the app, or if this one would cover everything.

Basically the app uses Facebook connect to let the user send messages to their FB friends' phones. In order to do this I need to store the users FB ID and device ID together on the server. Would I need an additional SSL certificate for this? Or would the one that is being used in the app for APNS be sufficient for both tasks? I'm not particularly experienced with server based things, so the simpler this can be explained the better.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you need only one SSL but make sure when you register your domain for SSL is should be ***.domainname.com** not **domainname.com** including  * . its include your all sub domains

*Thanks*

Comment: OK, and the SSL from Apple is sufficient? It's not somehow stripped down to only work with APNS?

Comment: @user1182532 you can get from any where and its work any where 
but don't forget to check its terms maybe some make its limited use 
but normally its not limited

Comment: Just confirming that you were exactly right, no other SSL certificates were needed - just in case anyone else has the same question in future. Thank you.

Comment: @TheBestBigAl nice you are right your comment maybe help some one :)